# Rails 5.1: Foreign key mismatch for old rails schema

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-on-rails-5.1

Context: On Rails 5.1 the default for Primary Keys changed from Int to BigInt (PR > https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/26266).

I am working on a new `Rails 5.1` app which reuses some models from another `Rails 4.0` app.

When I run the specs, I have a script that basically loads the `Rails 4.0` app's `schema.rb` from its repo, to create a temp database, so I can use those "external" models (from that other DB) when running tests.

The issue is that given the other app created the `schema.rb` file on `Rails 4.0`, all *Foreign Keys* are `integers`.

The `Rails 4.0` schema file looks like this:

```
create_table "companies", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
end

create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name",
    t.integer  "company_id", limit: 4, null: false
end

add_foreign_key "users", "companies"
```

Therefore, when I run tests on the new `Rails 5.1` app, it loads that other app schema (the one added above), but when creating the **Companies** table, it **sets the Primary Key as `BigInt` instead of `integer`**. But the Foreign Key is an `integer`.

That mismatch is messing up with MySQL:

> ActiveRecord::MismatchedForeignKey: Column `company_id` on table
>   `users` has a type of `int(11)`. This does not match column `id` on
>   `companies`, which has type `bigint(20)`. To resolve this issue,
>   change the type of the `company_id` column on `users` to be :integer.
>   (For example `t.integer company_id`).

I know I could just change all Foreign Keys from that schema to be a BigInt. But I want to try avoiding that solution, given there are quite a lot of Foreign Keys, and in multiple DBs.

Any ideas on how to solve this issue? Or any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify an integer type for the primary key for the new table; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44390225/how-to-turn-off-bigint-primary-keys-in-rails-5-1).  That would give you the opportunity to migrate to `bigint` primary keys without being rushed into it.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the `type` as `integer`, for example:

```
t.references :company, type: :integer, foreign_key: true, null: false
```